# Why is the number of strings 79 instead of 80 for this counting problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Consider strings of length six consisting of the characters a, b, c,
>   and d. How many such strings are there that start with abc or end with
>   cccc?

How I approached the problem
String 1, start with abc, therefore there are $4^3$ possibilities
String 2, ends with cccc, therefore there are $4^2$ possibilities

= 64 + 16 = 80.

Yet the answer in my book is 79. Can someone explain how this is the answer?

Comment: You counted abcccc twice!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ahhh! Thank you, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @lordsharktheunknown that should be an answer too.